# How do I remove a chuck that got stuck during removal?

Tags: tools, drill, chuck

I was in the process of removing a keyless  chuck on a cordless drill. I removed the screw from the chuck first and for some unknown reason managed to close the teeth on the chuck without inserting an allen wrench and they're now stuck. Tried everything to open them to get the allen in there but nothing has worked so far. What can I do to get this thing removed?

Comment: It's very difficult to follow your question.  Please consider adding a photo and a better explanation of what you are trying to do.

Comment: Pic of the chuck, please.

Comment: I managed to remove it with vice grips and a hammer. This is after it was removed: https://imgur.com/a/Me635tc

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to open up the teeth so ended up using vice grips on the chuck itself. A few good whacks with a hammer to loosen it and used the drill's power to unthread the rest of the way.

Answer (score 0):

If you have jammed it shut then a cutting disc in a grinder may be the best solution.

Take care not to damage the threads or spindle.